# Modulus in Prolog

Tags: prolog

I am trying to use a conditional statement if N is even do something otherwise do something else.
Here is some part of my code where I am doing this:

```
(N,Lines,1):-write(N),nl,
(    mod(N,2) = 0 ->
 write('Hello'),nl,write('Again Hello')

;
    foo(N,Lines)

).
```

But even if I give N=6 it goes into `foo(N,Lines)` i.e else part. It is not going into if part. Can someone please tell me where I'm wrong?

Comment: To test equality of arithmetic expressions, use `(=:=)/2` instead of `(=)/2`, for example: `mod(N, 2) =:= 0`.

Comment: Sorry, I originally posted an answer that was factually wrong, at least using SWI-Prolog (I usually use eclipse, which has mod/3).

Answer (score 5):

Instead of writing it as `mod(N,2) = 0` write `0 is mod(N,2)` or `0 =:= mod(N,2)` (Like mat said in the comments)

Like:

```
write(N),nl,
(    0 is mod(N,2) ->
 write('Hello'),nl,write('Again Hello')
;
    foo(N,Lines)
).
```

and if `N=6`, like in your example, I get:

```
6
Hello
Again Hello
true.
```

There are some examples on prolog arithmetics [here](http://cs.union.edu/~striegnk/learn-prolog-now/html/node39.html).

Comment: It is better to use (=:=)/2 instead of (is/2) when both arguments are already instantiated.